# Pandas DataFrame dynamic subgroup operation

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a "Perf" dataframe with people performance data over time. 
The index is a timstamp and the columns are the persons name.
There are 100 persons (columns) and each person belongs to one of 10 groups, however the group assignment is dynamic, everyday each person could be assigned to a different group.
So there is a second "Group" DataFrame of the same shape than "Perf" that contains group number (0-9) for each timestamp and person.

The question is how can I elegantly do a mean subtraction everyday for each person with regards to its group assignment?
One method that is really slow is:

```
for g in range(10):
    Perf[Group==g] -= Perf[Group==g].mean(1)
```

But this is really slow, I'm sure there is a way to do it in one shot with Pandas.

here is an concrete example:

scores represents the score for each person (0-4) for 10 days (0-9):

In [8]: perf = DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,5))

In [9]: perf

Out[9]:

```
      0         1         2         3         4 

0  0.945575 -0.805883  1.338865  0.420829 -1.074329 

1 -1.086116  0.430230  1.296153  0.527612  1.269646 

2  0.705276 -1.409828  2.859838 -0.769508  1.520295 

3  0.331860 -0.217884  0.962576 -0.495888 -1.083996 

4  0.402625  0.018885 -0.260516 -0.547802 -0.995959 

5  2.168944 -0.361657  0.184537  0.391014  0.972161 

6  1.959699  0.590739 -0.781736  1.059761  1.080997 

7  2.090273 -2.446399  0.553785  0.806368 -0.786343 

8  0.441160 -2.320302 -1.981387  2.190607  0.345626 

9 -0.276013 -1.319214  1.339096  0.269680 -0.509884
```

Then I've got some grouping dataframe that for each day shows the group association of each one of the 5 persons, the grouping changes everyday.

```
In [20]: grouping 

Out[20]: 

  0 1 2 3 4 

0 3 1 2 1 2 

1 3 1 2 2 1 

2 2 2 3 1 1 

3 1 2 2 3 1 

4 3 2 1 2 1 

5 2 1 1 2 3 

6 1 2 1 2 3 

7 2 2 1 1 3 

8 2 1 2 1 3 

9 1 3 2 1 2
```

I want to modify Perf such that for each day I subtract for each person the mean score of its group.

for example for day 0 it will be 0.0 -0.613356 1.206597 0.613356 -1.206597

I want to do it in 1 line without loops. Groupby seems to be the function to use, but I couldn't use efficiently its output to perform the mean subtract operation on the original matrix.

Comment: Please post raw input data, code to create your df and desired output, thanks

Comment: Yeah, some sample data would be good.  You might want something like `Perf.groupby('Group').transform('mean')`?  In any event, you probably want to look at the groupby docs if you haven't already  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html